# bazel build android_binary with Guava dependency complains about min_sdk_version despite being set in manifest

Tags: java, android, guava, bazel

UPDATE:
I decided to try an experiment.  I went through the [bazel android tutorial](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/tutorial/android-app.html) and got it to work.  I then tried making a small change to add a dependency on Guava and added the dep to the `BUILD` file.  The result - I was able to reproduce the issue there as well.  So it's definitely something to do with including Guava, but why it should be deciding that I want API level 13 I do not know.

One of the main advantages of using Java/Android is that I can reuse code, so it's not good if I have to separate/duplicate build targets to have android-specific versions that pull in an android version of Guava.  If I was avoiding Java8, maybe that would make sense, but my intent is to keep `minSdkVersion` above 24 and use the Java8 features... I don't understand where "current version 13" is coming from that prevents this.

TL:DR;

running `bazel build [android_binary_target]` fails with

```
ERROR: C:/_bazel_out/z2b54lqx/external/maven/BUILD:829:1: Dexing external/maven/_dx/com_google_guava_guava/guava-30.0-jre.jar_desugared.jar with applicable dexopts [] failed (Exit 1)
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: ERROR in com.google.common.collect.CollectCollectors.toImmutableBiMap:(Ljava/util/function/Function;Ljava/util/function/Function;)Ljava/util/stream/Collector;: invoking a static interface method java.util.
stream.Collector.of:(Ljava/util/function/Supplier;Ljava/util/function/BiConsumer;Ljava/util/function/BinaryOperator;Ljava/util/function/Function;[Ljava/util/stream/Collector$Characteristics;)Ljava/util/stream/Collector; strictly requires --min-sdk-version >= 24 (blocked at current A
PI level 13)
```

This happens despite all included `AndroidManifest.xml` files specifying `minSdkVersion="28"`.  I have no idea where "current API level 13" is coming from.

Long version:
I'm working on porting my personal codebase from gradle to bazel.  I've reached the point of porting the first android app, which is just a little demo of another library I have for some LaTeX-style formatting.  That library has common core code that is not android specific and there is a separate target for the android implementations. The directory structure, `BUILD` files, and `AndroidManifest.xml` are described below.

The common code makes heavy use of `Guava` and since it is not android-specific it does not use the android-specific guava versions.  I would not expect this to matter for sufficiently high minSdkVersion.  I recognize that Guava is big and not great for android as a complete block... I'm considering trying to change my dependence on it so something where I can pick and choose individual packages within Guava rather than the whole thing, but this seems to unrelated to what I'm seeing where the build insists it's using API level 13 when this doesn't seem to be specified anywhere.

I'd really like to avoid having to have separate targets/deps for common code that will sometimes be used for android and sometimes not... e.g. my java/com/bdl/latex/core package which depends on guava shouldn't use android-specific guava deps as it is not specific to android.

Any idea why the system thinks it's using API level 13?
What do I need to do to make it recognize the minSdkVersion from my AndroidManifest?

WORKSPACE just includes `android_sdk_repository(name = "androidsdk")` without specifying a version, so it should use my highest installed (30).  I've verified that I have versions above 24 installed (Everything 25-30),
Versions of tools:
Android SDK tools: 26.1.1
Platform-Tools: 30.0.5

Directory structure:

```
java/com/bdl
  latex - the public API of the latex package.
    core - main classes for common functionality, some public stuff that I haven't separated yet.
    graphics - interfaces allowing for implementations support both Android and AWT
    android - Android-specific implementations
       demo - where all my demo app code lives.
```

And the relevant files:

`java/com/bdl/latex/android/BUILD:` - BUILD for the android-specific implementations

```
android_library(
    name = "android",
    srcs = glob(["*.java"]),
    manifest = "AndroidManifest.xml",
    resource_files = glob(["res/**/*.*"]),
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    deps = [
        "//ext/google:guava", # //ext are local exports of maven repos
        "//ext/google/dagger",
        "//ext/java:jsr305_annotations",
        "//ext/javax:inject",
        "//java/com/bdl/android/dagger",
        "//java/com/bdl/latex",
        "//java/com/bdl/latex/core",
        "//java/com/bdl/latex/graphics:common",
    ],
)
```

`java/com/bdl/latex/android/AndroidManifest.xml`:

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.bdl.latex.android">

  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="28"/>
</manifest>
```

`java/com/bdl/latex/android/demo/BUILD:` - root for the app... maybe this could be combined with the demo/app package, but for now I'm following the pattern from the bazel android tutorial where the binary and library targets are in separate packages with separate `AndroidManifest.xml` files.

```
android_binary(
    name = "app",
    manifest = "AndroidManifest.xml",
    multidex = "native",
    deps = ["//java/com/bdl/latex/android/demo/app:demo"],
)
```

`java/com/bdl/latex/android/demo/AndroidManifest.xml`:

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.bdl.latex.android.demo"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0" >

  <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="28"
    android:targetSdkVersion="28" />

</manifest>
```

and finally the app package:

`java/com/bdl/latex/android/demo/app/BUILD:`

```
android_library(
    name = "demo",
    srcs = glob(["*.java"]),
    manifest = "AndroidManifest.xml",
    resource_files = glob(["res/**/*"]),
    visibility = ["//java/com/bdl/latex/android/demo:__subpackages__"],
    deps = [
        "//ext/android:support",
        "//ext/google/dagger",
        "//ext/google/dagger:android",
        "//ext/javax:inject",
        "//java/com/bdl/android/dagger",
        "//java/com/bdl/latex/android",
        "//java/com/bdl/latex/core",
    ],
)
```

`java/com/bdl/latex/android/demo/app/AndroidManifest.xml:`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.bdl.latex.android.demo.app">

  <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="28"
    android:targetSdkVersion="28"/>

  <application
    android:name=".AndroidLatexDemoApp"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
      android:name=".LaTeXActivity"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>

</manifest>
```

I'm probably just holding it wrong, so I'm hoping there's a simple fix:

Comment: in `demo/app/BUILD`, I think using `manifest = "src/main/AppAndroidManifest.xml",` might help. And the binary should point to app module manifest file like `manifest = "//demo:src/main/AndroidManifest.xml",`

Comment: Let me know if it helps.

Comment: There are no directories in the project named "src" or "main," and creating them under `demo/app` just to move the manifest file there and then reference its new location has no effect.  I know the location scheme for the files is not an issue as I was able to run the tutorial from the bazel site with modifications for my directory structure.

Comment: It's not an exact duplicate, but should be good enough to solve the issue... because `--min-sdk-version` hints for compile-time. Downgrading Guava might also work; better use the Android version instead of the JRE version.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a duplicate at all.  I'm not trying to compile at a specific version, I'm trying to figure out why the inclusion of guava fools bazel into thinking I'm on an sdk version that I don't specify anywhere. 

I'm not sure what the `--min-sdk-version` flag reference means as there is no such flag for `bazel build`  Adding `api_level=28` to my WORKSPACE does not solve the issue.

Using the Guava android version is to be avoided if at all possible because I have transient deps on Guava through code that is intended to be shared with non-android code.

Comment: ditto with adding "minSdkVersion": "28" in my `android_binary` target.  This also does not resolve things.